# How can I get timecode start times and chapter names as plain text from a video which has chapter markers?

Tags: youtube, export, timecode, metadata

**Source**: Quicktime movie or MP4 container which has chapter markers.

**Intended output**: Plain text for use in YouTube or similar services. Chapter start time code as (HH:)MM:SS at the beginning of the line followed by the chapter name.

```
00:00 Intro
00:30 Another Chapter
02:00 Fin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LosslessCut](https://mifi.no/losslesscut/) (GUI for ffmpeg and ffprobe, multi-platform, free)

1. Open video file with video markers.
2. A dialog opens:

> This file has embedded chapters. Do you want to import the chapters as cut-segments?

- Click "Import chapters"

3. Menu > File > Export project > Start times as Youtube Chapters
4. A dialog with a multi line text area opens:

- Copy the desired chapter names and timecodes
- Offers a "copy all" button for your convenience too.

---

[image: LossLessCut chapter markers 2 Import dialog]
[image: LossLessCut chapter markers 3 Export start time as YouTube chapters]
[image: LossLessCut chapter markers 4 Copy timecode and chapters]

Comment: This works fine for me with smaller files but it doesn't seem to work for large files (~600GB). Do you have any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: The LossLessCut [website](https://mifi.no/losslesscut/) mentions "Shave gigabytes off video and audio files in seconds" so I guess is rather well suited for handling large file sizes. But maybe the chapter function in particularly is not memory optimized? Try ask at their Github [discussion forum](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/discussions).